# Strange behaviour with binding in Groovy based DSL

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, dsl

I have a Groovy based DSL in which I want to access variables from declared bindings. Here's my DSL implementation:

```
class Bar {
    String barVal

    void bar(String bar) {
        this.barVal = bar
    }
}

class Foo {
    Bar bar

    void foo(@DelegatesTo(value = Bar, strategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST) closure) {
        def bar = new Bar()
        def code = closure.rehydrate(bar, null, null)
        code()
        this.bar = bar
    }
}

abstract class MyScript extends Script  {

    Foo dslEntryPoint(@DelegatesTo(value = Foo, strategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST) closure) {
        def foo = new Foo()
        def code = closure.rehydrate(foo, null, null)
        code()
        foo
    }
}
```

And here's an example of my DSL and how I run it:

```
def DSL_NOT_WORKING = """
    dslEntryPoint() {
        foo {
            bar magicValue
        }
    }
"""

def DSL_OK = """
    def myMagicValue = magicValue
    dslEntryPoint() {
        foo {
            bar myMagicValue
        }
    }
"""

CompilerConfiguration config = new CompilerConfiguration(CompilerConfiguration.DEFAULT)
config.scriptBaseClass = MyScript.class.name
GroovyClassLoader groovyClassLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader(), config)
Class<Script> clazz = groovyClassLoader.parseClass(DSL_NOT_WORKING)
Binding binding = new Binding()
binding.setVariable('magicValue', '42')
Script script = InvokerHelper.createScript(clazz, binding)
Foo foo = script.run() as Foo
assert foo.bar.barVal == '42'
```

As you can see, when I bind the variable with `def` (`DSL_OK`), I can access its value in my DSL, whereas otherwise (`DSL_NOT_WORKING`) I get a

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'magicValue' on null object
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I access the variable `magicValue` without the `def` helper declaration? I think it has something to do with calling `rehydrate` on the closure where I could pass `this` instead of `null`, but this does not seem to work with nested object hierarchies (Foo->Bar).

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my usage of `rehydrate` which overrides the owner and delegate with `null`. Instead of bookkeeping the owner and delegate in the nested object hierarchy, it is much simpler to just use a plain delegate instead:

```
Foo dslEntryPoint(@DelegatesTo(Foo) closure) {
  Foo foo = new Foo()
  closure.delegate = foo
  closure.call()
  foo
}
```